# Populating a textview of a class with data from another class

Tags: android

I have developed some sms application and I can't figure out how to solve this issue... in one layout I am displaying two textviews to display the number and the date of the sms... that works fine...

But now I am implementing the onListItemClick and I want that when list item is clicked the whole messages from the database should load into the new view.... How can I accomplish that...

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


        dba.open();

        Cursor c=dba.executeQuery("select rowid _id,* from messages where rowid="+position+";");
        Log.v(tag, "value count"+ c.getCount());
        if(c.getCount()>0)
        {
            Log.v(tag, "value count"+c.getCount());
            c.moveToPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                String mesage = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("msg"));

                Log.v("Value passed to class", mesage);
                intent.putExtra(name, mesage);

            intent.setClass(this, NewInterface.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }

    }
```

And here is the code of the other class to which I am passing data.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.messages);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMessages);
        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null)
        {
            Log.v("Value got from class", bundle.getString("name"));
            tv4.setText(bundle.getString("name"));
        }
```

The list view is populated via this method from database containing the phone numbers....

private void openAndQueryDatabase() {

```
    newDB=new DBAdapter(this);

    try {

        newDB.open();
        Cursor c = newDB.executeQuery("select distinct nm,rowid _id from messages");

        if (c != null ) {

            if  (c.moveToFirst()) 
                Log.v(tag, "Stage 1");{
                do {

                    String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nm"));
                    Log.v(tag, firstName);
                //  String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("dt"));

                    results.add(firstName);


                }while (c.moveToNext());
                Log.v(tag, "Stage 1");
            } 
        }
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing

Comment: i want that when a user clicks a certain listitem it gets the phone number that is displayed on the specific listviewitem and then perform a database query on that number and fetch the messages and pass that data to another classs for displaying it in a different layout...

Comment: can you add your getview() or the what exactly the listview item contain i mean the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of List item you are opening a db to fetch data based on position clicked. Instead of trying to read the whole datain your first Activity, why don't you just pass the int position to the next Activity using Intent and then make the database query there. It would be easier and make more sense. If you still want to pass the wholde data , use a code similar to the one below (replacing your `if(c.getCount>0)` block):

```
 ArrayList<String> arrayList ;

            Cursor c=null;
            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                int x= c.getCount();
                int  y =c.getColumnIndex("msg");
            arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(x);
                for(int a=0;a<x;a++){
c.moveToPosition(a);                    
arrayList.add(c.getString(y));

                }
                  Intent intent = new Intent(this,NewInterface.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("msgs",arrayList );
            startActivity(intent);
            }
```

To get the number from one of the textViews of your clicked row of ListView:

```
TextView tv1=(TextView)v.findViewbyId(R.id.number)//Replace this with id of tv displaying numbers
String number = tv1.getText().toString();
```

Add these lines in your onListItemClick and then use this number in your query.

Comment: but the problem is that... when i get the position variable it returns an int...while i need  the phone number which is displayed on the list... and then according to that phone number perform a database query....hope u get me..

Comment: the listview is displaying numbers not a textview....its not a textview thats being clicked its a listviewitem thats being clicked and on the basis of that listviewclick i want to populate a textview with the data from database...

Comment: did u add the above two lines?

Comment: i got the listitem content as this....
String s = (String)((Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position)).getString();